# PHP: refer to extracted array variables

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have some code that fills an array with data that I then need to convert into a URL with query.  The number of elements in the array is unknown.

```
extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "pp_");
```

Let's say I have two elements, I need to build a URL with those.  So I have:

```
$pp_0 and $pp_1
```

The query parameters need to look like:

```
...&pp={contents of $pp_0}&pp={contents of $pp_1};;
```

Where the values of the pp= parameters are $pp_0 and $pp_1 respectively.

I've been racking my brain for hours on how to get this to work.

Comment: Why do you extract them in the first place? Why not keep them in the array and loop it?

Comment: Why do you have to build an URL with the same key multiple times? It would be an invalid URL. Do you mean `pp[]=...&pp[]=...`? Or `pp_1=...&pp_2=...`? Then, you should use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to avoid possible issues (encoding, ...) instead of creating the URL manually. Another note, the extracted variables are `$pp__0`,`$pp__1`, with two underscore, [example](https://3v4l.org/hfSDX).

Answer (score 0):

You can either loop the values in the array and build the string, or use implode.

Implode method:

```
$arr =['pp_1' => 1, 'pp_2' => 2, 'pp_3' => 3];

Echo "&pp=" .implode("&pp=", $arr) . ";";
```

https://3v4l.org/UpoV9

Loop method:

```
$str ="";
Foreach($arr as $pp){
    $str .= "&pp=" . $pp;
}
$str .= ";";
Echo $str;
```

https://3v4l.org/li8Kf

The output is the same, but I think you can have more control in the loop method.
Implode takes all values and implode them, looping gives you the option to add an if inside and check the keys or values before joining them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was over complicating it. Looks like http_build_query is what I want to be using, didn’t know it existed.